# Why does browser remove `body` from `foreignObject` element

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I pasted the following into the html:

```
<svg width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <foreignObject width="100" height="50" requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <p>Here is a paragraph that requires word wrap</p>
        </body>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

However, it's represented as

```
<svg width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <foreignobject width="100" height="50" requiredextensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <!-- XHTML content goes here -->      
        <p>Here is a paragraph that requires word wrap</p>  
    </foreignobject>
</svg>
```

in the DOM. Why is `body` removed?

[Here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/foreignobject-hey-youve-got-html-in-my-svg), for example, `body` stays inside the DOM.

Comment: I believe that [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) has a great explanation - `There can be only one <body> element in a document.`.

Comment: "Because reasons", but basically there can only be one `<body>` element in an HTML document.

Comment: Because the `<body>` tag is taken. Just like you would expect `<p>` to act as a paragraph, `<body>` acts like an HTML body tag, of which there can be only one in the document.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, as I understand it, `foreignObject` element allows for custom html, including `body` tag. The web page in the app I'm working on has many `body` elements inside `foreignobject` tags

Comment: @Maximus if you include html in an svg document, then you could use multiple `body` tags, but øu haven an inline `svg` within `html`.

Comment: @t.niese, how can I do that? I tried to include an `svg` document with <object> tag, but then the content is rendered inside `#document` tag. This is not how I see the svg elements rendered inside the page I'm exploring